# Conflict on IIS 7.5 with web.config when mixing different versions of ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am setting up a new website on new web servers that are running IIS 7.5, which is new to me.  I have ran into a problem when deploying an ASP.NET app that is using the 4.0 framework.  I get error messages about conflicts with the web.config file associated with the Default Web Site.  The asp.net app defined in the default website is using the 2.0 framework currently.

My 4.0 framework app is defined as an application under the default website.  Both are using different Application Pools.

I tried adding this to my 4.0 apps config file, but it did not seem to help:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

How do I get around this web.config conflict issue?

Update for error message:

```
There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined.

The config file for the 4.0 app does not even have this section.  The default website app does have this.
```

Comment: Can you post the error message ?

Comment: @Robotsushi: Updated with the error message.  If I remove the offending entry from the default site config, I get an issue with the framework version to use in compilation: 3.5 vs 4.0.  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a documented problem, with a [solution](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc245724860).

Essentially, you will be moving the configSections information out of the parent 2.0 application's web.config, and instead putting it into a shared 2.0 specific parent web.config (found in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG and/or C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG), and then using the location tag to hide the rest of your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the location tag around the system.web section of the default web application?  It sounds like that is what you want to prevent inheritance on, not the 4.0 app (if I understand you right, the 4.0 app is the "child" app of the 2.0 default app).

Comment: I tried that just now, but it did not change anything. Same error message.

Comment: Did a bit more reading.  The location tag can only apply to something like the system.web section, and not configSections, which is where the initial issue is at.

Comment: While you can't put a location tag around the configSections area, you can put it around the elements that you define later in the file (for example, if you have a configSection defining a "spring" section, you can put the location tag around the `<spring>...</spring>` section.  Not sure if that will fix your problem, but worth a try.  Sorry I don't have a similar environment set up currently, otherwise I'd try it myself.