# IIS7 Application within an Application issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have a working asp.net 4.0 application inside IIS. We will call this 'App A'.

I want to add a completely separate 4.0 application from within it that has no dependencies or is related to it at all. We will call this 'App B'.

I moved App B inside the root of App A and Converted it to a Web App and then assigned it to its own seperate App Pool.

When i try to access App B, it is giving me errors(Could not load file or assembly) that DLL's are missing in App B that are only in App A and have no relation or dependencies in App B as it is completely different.

Any ideas how to get App B to run completely separate from App A, when nested in its root?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5046378/656243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> 
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- ... -->
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

[Nested ASP.NET 'application' within IIS inheriting parent config values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144117/nested-asp-net-application-within-iis-inheriting-parent-config-values)